# Animate transition between normal and highlighted state of a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton, performselector

I want to animate the transition between normal and highlighted state of a UIButton.

I put 2 images as background of the two states in IB and wrote the following code for TouchUpInside event:

```
- (void) animate {
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.myButton
                      duration:2
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{ self.myButton.highlighted = YES; }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {[UIView transitionWithView:self.myButton
                                                                   duration:2
                                                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                                                 animations:^{ self.myButton.highlighted = NO; }
                                                                 completion:nil];}
     ];
}
```

In this way the animation is not started regularly and in particular if I tap quickly on the button.

I found that by preceding the above method with the following (linked to the UIButton in place of the previous one) the animation works without any problem ... but I don't understand the reason !

Could someone explain what exactly happens when I add this last method ?

```
- (void) firstThis {

    [self performSelector: @selector(animate) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0];
}
```

Thanks,
Corrado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

performSelector always schedules your method to be performed later (in this case on main), even if you set delay = 0. So, in your case the system gets a chance to properly start/stop animations and/or finish other stuff, like for example: the automatic highlighting of the button that happens because of touch-down events. The system starts the animation after having finished its own highlight animation of the button. The direct call interferes with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be not to use a UIButton at all (since you are trying to avoid some of its inherited behavior). There are a few different approaches you could use. I would consider using a UIImageView instead, and adding a gesture recognizer to its frame in code. Then you can animate the highlighting however you like, because the system isn't trying to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks ... I'll try your suggestion